# TypeScript: cannot find name async/await

Tags: typescript, async-await

I'm using `typescript@next` and I want to compile my code to `es5`, but each time I'm using `async` or `await` keywords the compiler errors with that message:

```
Cannot find name 'await'.
```

Heres my libs: `dom`, `es2015`, `es2016`, `es2017`.

Code example:

```
let asyncFn = () => {
   return new Promise((resolve:Function)=>{resolve(2)})
}
// should log `2`
console.log(await asyncFn())
```

Such things are possible even with `typescript@2.0.x`, I've tried it, but somehow I am unable to compile my code anyway.

Comment: Please post your code. Is your function marked with `async`?

Comment: no, it's not, but I don't need to mark my scope as 'async', right? afaik that's only syntastic sugar for `Promise`

Comment: [Read the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/release-notes/typescript-1.7.html): "Asynchronous functions are prefixed with the async keyword"

Comment: @Roomy: `async` and `await` are a *pair* of keywords. You can't use `await` unless it's within an `async` scope.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to use your asyncFn inside a function marked as an 'async' function.  For example:

```
async someAsyncCode() {
    let asyncFn = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve: Function) => { resolve(2); });
    }
    // should log `2`
    console.log(await asyncFn());
}
```

Comment: Pretty shocking that even the dumb TypeScript compiler can't give a better error message. Something like `await cannot be used outside of an async scope` would have been fine.