# await (async ():Type => {return value})() :: error Cannot find name 'await'.ts(2304)

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await

```js
// Does not work - Cannot find name 'await'.ts(2304)
let someVariable = await (async ():someType => {
   // i need to use await inside here so i need it async
   return someValue;
})();

// does work, but not async.
let someVariable2 = (():someType => {
   // cant use await inside
   return someValue
})();
```

i tried wrapping await inside another set of curved brackets, still doesnt work. yes i know i can declare a function then call it like you would normally, but i'd rather have it like this. if it isnt possible then ill go back to the normal way.

i do not know fully what `()` does in cases like this, but im assuming it returns the object inside. is it possible to use async/await like this? if possible would also like to learn more about how `()` works in cases like this.

code runs on Deno
**edit:** people saying "await must be used inside an async block" Deno has top-level await.

Clarifying.

```js
// this is top-level
async function somefunc() {}
await somefunc(); // this WORKS on deno.
```

issue is `let var = await(async () => {})()` creates said error, and i am trying to find a way to fix this with a other way than declaring then await it

edit: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38483

Comment: You can only `await` from within an `async` function, and presumably you run it from the global scope.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript: cannot find name async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40400806/typescript-cannot-find-name-async-await)

Comment: deno has top-level await, no need to put it inside an async block

Comment: "Deno has top-level await" --- typescript does not. It does not matter where it eventually runs, you need to compile it first.

Comment: @zerkms with deno & an ide extension(supressing/changing errors) it does. deno runs typescript without tsc

Comment: @eme2n if all runs fine, what's your problem again?

Comment: @zerkms eg ``async function eg() {}; await eg()`` works top-level, but using ``await (async () => {})()`` does not and returns said error

Comment: @eme2n then report it as a bug: syntactically it's fine

Comment: @zerkms will do

Answer (score 1):

Await has to be called inside a async function.

```js
  const aFunc = async () =>{
      let someVariable = await (async ():someType => {
         const someValue = await asyncFunc()
         return someValue;
      })();
      // Now you get the value
      console.log(someVariable)
}
aFunc()
```

Now You can call `aFunc` function to make it work

Comment: Deno has top-level await

Comment: @eme2n Right, does my code still meet your requirement?.
Deno is new, You can check this issue discussion here: https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/471

Comment: the issue is closed and top-level await is implemented(i have multiple deno apps using it) look at root comments

Answer (score 1):

`await` can only within an async block. Make sure outside await is also within an async block or you can save the promise within **someVariable**.

```
let someVariable = (async ():someType => {
   return someValue;
})();

someVariable.then((result) => {
 // result contains whatever u returned in the async block.
})
```

```js
const someVariable = (async () => {
  const result = await Promise.resolve('Hey there!')
  return result;
})()

someVariable.then(result => console.log({ result }))
```

Comment: Deno has top-level await